# jQuery contents is not a function

Tags: jquery, html

This jQuery code tries to get all the comments elements in a page, but is returning error when run in the browser console.

> TypeError: $(...).contents is not a function

How can I get all the comments nodes in a page? Thankx

```
$("*").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 8;
})
```

Comment: can you post the html

Comment: The contains function should have a parameter

Comment: Are you sure the web page you are trying to run the script has jquery lib? I ask the question because you said you run the script in browser console which relies on the jquery availability in the active webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ithink `$` refers to some other library in your page, so use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Also check jQuery library is included before the code in your page.

```
jQuery("*").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 8;
})
```

---

Or use a closure to get the `$` as `jQuery` inside the function

```
(function($){
    $("*").contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType == 8;
    })
})(jQuery);
```

or

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("*").contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType == 8;
    })
})
```

Read more here : [Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

---

Also don't forget to wrap the code by [document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: He must wait for the page load too.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH :  that's true , but that doesn't throw the error